# Ignore a part of a path in react-router?

Tags: react-router

I am using react-router and I would like to render a component if I have a defined path.

I want to render to myComponent1 if my path has the following format: https://localhost:3000/somethingHere/myComponent1

I would like something that would ignore the middle of path

```
<Route path="/...jump this part.../myComponent1" component={mypathComponent}>
```

Do you know how to do it ?
Another possibility is to render to the component if the word myComponent1 belongs to my path. Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: do you mean `path="/:anything/myComponent1"` ?

Comment: But there is no need that ":anything" refers to something ?

Comment: it's just a variable, it can be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<Route path="/:id*/myComponent1" component={mypathComponent}>
```

It will match these paths:

```
/myComponent1
/mine/myComponent1
/mine/yours/myComponent1
```